# Horizontal drop menu (child menu) positioning differently in chrome, ie9, firefox, and safari

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9, drop-down-menu

i have spent 3 days trying to figure out this issue and cannot come up with a viable solution.

ive even tried using javascript to load stylesheets tailored to each browser, but even that didnt work.

my problem is my horizontal menu (http://mydomainsample.com/fire_rebuild) is displaying perfectly fine i n chrome, but when i load in safari or firefox, the child menu is way out of position. oddly enough IE(9) is closer to being correct than the other two, but even thats not quite correct.

i have played with the stylesheet trying to figure it out, but when i get it right in fff, safari, or ie its screwed up in chrome.

i cant seem to find a solution that works in all browsers.

can someone please help me find a solution to this? 
ive tried using a different menu but this one looks the best and any vertical drops ive used give me z-index problems between the menu and the slideshow that i cant seem to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think src is an optional attribute for link tags. Replace it with hrefs like the first two. When I look at the page in firefox, I do not see two files above being imported.

The order of the files in those link tags are very important as well.

href="stylesheets/reset.css"

href="stylesheets/coda-slider-2.0.css"

I do not know if you already have them but firefox and chrome has the firebug and web developer plugins that makes life easier.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has been updated to v1.7.2; I would update all your plugins & see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remove all the javascript you applied to match for different browsers.
Then Remove the `width:750px;` and  `left: 548px;` on style.css line 83 (ul#nav li:hover > ul)

Hope this will solve your problem

Also your page width is 1220px. Stick with the 960px width in order to compatible with small screen sizes.